# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function is not a valid method for this service

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

When I try to access a function in wsdl with some data(using soap client in php) I am getting the following error.

```
Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function function_nameis not a valid method for this service
```

Any help?

Comment: Is that the actual error? Because if so I guess you have taken a template file from the service provider, and tried to make a call to a service function called `function_name` - which is unlikely to be the actual name of a function. You are supposed to replace `function_name` with the name of the function you are calling, it's just a placeholder to show you where the function name would go. The service provider likely provides documentation. I suggest you read it. Properly.

Comment: Hi Dave thanks for response.that is not original error message.i replaced actual function name with 'function_name'

Comment: Well even so, the error is telling you that the function name is not valid for that service you are trying to consume so re-check the docs and make sure the function name is valid, and if it is, contact the service provider.

Comment: I have same issue when upgrade from PHP 5.6 to 7. In 7 method __getFunctions() says that function has but __call throws error. Problem was in wsdl cache. I changed soap.wsdl_cache_dir in php.ini of php7 and problem was solved

Comment: Hello guys, I have the same issue, changed to what @blackbass1988 ?

Answer (score 26):

If you want to execute a function that SOAP can not find - it is possible that PHP cached the wsdl file.

Add this:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
```

to disable the caching.

Comment: I added this line, still getting the same error, what should i do?

Answer (score 2):

Two possible solutions :

1. try to see if the function really exists with the snippet of code there : [PHP SoapClient request: not a valid method for this service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817430/php-soapclient-request-not-a-valid-method-for-this-service)
2. Also, once you have displayed the list of available function calls, take care that if your WSDL is generated by a Java SOAP server, you might have several functions named "service" (or with the same name). Only the first one will be recognized and used by the PHP SOAP client. You need to manually rename all your  in the WSDL !

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and finally decided to check my php error log.

In ***php.ini*** enable `always_populate_raw_post_data = -1` and restart the server .

My PHP version is **5.6.8**

Answer (score 0):

Just add Parameters,Return type and Method of web service in comments at the top of the function. It will work. I tried its working.

```
/**
 * @param string the symbol of the stock
 * @return float the stock price
 * @soap
 */
public function getPrice($symbol)
{
    //...return stock price for $symbol
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In our situation this exception occurred when upgrading from PHP5.6 to PHP7. For us disabling the WSDL cache did also work.

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
```

Also see: http://lornajane.net/posts/2015/soapfault-when-switching-php-versions