# PHP Soap Client call to WCF service?

Tags: wcf, soap, soap-client, wcf-binding, nusoap

How to do this, I m new Soap API, Any sample Code
 $soapClient = new SoapClient("http://website.com/EComintegration/IntegrationService.svc?wsdl");

```
// Prepare SoapHeader parameters
$sh_param = array(
        'UserName'    =>    'admin',
        'Password'    =>    'admin');
        //'ClientID'    =>     1,
        //'OutletID'    =>     1,
        //'TerminalID'  =>     1);
$headers = new SoapHeader('http://website.com/EComintegration/IntegrationService.svc', 'UserCredentials', $sh_param);

// Prepare Soap Client
$soapClient->__setSoapHeaders(array($headers));

// Setup the RemoteFunction parameters
$ap_param = array(
    'Location' => 2,
    'DateFilter'=>'20200220'
);

// Call RemoteFunction ()
$error = 0;
try {
    $info = $soapClient->__call("GetInventory", array($ap_param));
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    $error = 1;
    print("
        alert('Sorry, blah returned the following ERROR: ".$fault->faultcode."-".$fault->faultstring.". We will now take you back to our home page.');
        window.location = 'main.php';
    ");
}

if ($error == 0) {       
    $auth_num = $info->ItemName;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

WCF is also an implementation of `SOAP web service`, thereby we should call the service like calling a SOAP web service. Please refer to the official documentation.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient
Also, here are some relevant links, wish it is helpful to you.
[How to consume a WCF Web Service that uses custom username validation with a PHP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652227/how-to-consume-a-wcf-web-service-that-uses-custom-username-validation-with-a-php)
https://forums.asp.net/t/1602125.aspx
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4abef020-7fb5-40ef-be77-227d329bb172/call-wcf-service-from-php-with-authentication?forum=wcf
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Wot code i have written, is that the proper one???
I m getting this error: (alert('Sorry, blah returned the following ERROR: Client-Function ("GetInventory") is not a valid method for this service. We will now take you back to our home page.'); window.location = 'main.php';)